# How to loop through a newly created element?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I am appending a new div every time I submit a form to a parent div. How would I loop through all of those newly created div elements? For example:

```
const parentDiv = document.querySelector("div")

form.addEventListener("submit", function formSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div")
    newDiv.classList.add("new-Div")
    parentDiv.append(newDiv) 
})
```

How could I loop through every newDiv element? I am trying something similar on a project I am working on and can't seem to find a solution. I have tried looping through using a for of loop but saying it is not iterable. Any help would be great!

Comment: "I have tried looping through using a for of loop " what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried looping through the `parentDiv` then yes it is not an iterable object. However, one solution could be just appending the new divs you create to a list and looping through the list like normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()`method, that will give you an array like object that you can iterate and access each element by their index like this

```
const newDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("new-Div");

for (let i = 0; i < newDiv.length; i++) {
    console.log(newDiv[i]);
  //do whatever
}
```